# Is it possible to have Livewire events in a Datatables render function

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I'm trying to open a modal and populate a form field with a model value.

The button to open the modal is embedded in the datatable config js and I'm thinking Livewire is running before the table is built.

The [datatable](https://datatables.net/) uses ajax to populate and `columnDefs` to configure rows.

The JS for the config of the datatable is in a `@push('scripts')` in the component blade file.

The (simplified) render function for the row is:

```
var datatable = thetable.DataTable({
    .....
    render: function (data, type, full, meta){
        return ('<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#UpdateModal" wire:click="edit(25)">Edit</a>');
    },
    .....
})
```

Clicking the button opens the modal but no XHR is made to the components edit function.

If I create an anchor in the same blade file as "normal" html:

```
<a href="#" wire:click="edit({{ 25 }})">test</button>
```

The XHR is called as expected.

So, I'm assuming Livewire doesn't know about the button - perhaps it ran before the table was built. Is there a way to force Livewire to wait?

I have tried to emit a Livewire event instead of `wire:click` = also no XHR.

I have seen the couple Laravel packages for Datatables. They don't suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done with emitted events and component listeners.

jQuery's `on` to bind to the future elements clicks which `livewire.emit` the events.

`protected listeners[]` in the component respond to the `emitted` events.